# product from one subcategory showing in other subcategory

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i am facing a problem... i am using woocommerce... i have one category. and inside that category 2 subcategory and inside every subcategory two subcategory.

1. parent category

   _sports 1

   __football

   __cricket

   _Sports 2

   __football

   __cricket

when i am posting product in sports 1 -> football its also showing in sports 2-> football...

its only showing in website. in wp-admin when i filter product with category name it does not show extra product. but when i open in website it show other subcategory product too.

if i open sports 2 category in website then it does not show the extra product. but if i open sports 2 -> football it showing other product.. from sports->football

thanks in advance... sorry for my bad english...

Comment: Change the last sports->football to sports 1-. football, I think that was by mistake . second thing, is your site live, then I want to visit the respective pages. and can you please post the code you are using to display products under subcategory ?

Comment: https://www.yesbilet.com/eventcategory/spor/futbol/sampiyonlar-ligi/galatasaray-biletleri/ this is the link...

Comment: if i use same name subcategory under other subcategory. its showing in other same name subcategory..... but i need same name. for my subcategory....

Comment: even product from sports 2-> football showing in sports 1-> football.,,,, this is problem of all subcategory... means if i post product in  sports1-> cricket it showing in sports 2-> cricket and product from sports2->cricket is showing in sports1-> cricket... but when i click on sports 1 0r sports 2 category its working fine. the problem with same name subcategories.....

Comment: Can you post the template code , I think you are not retrieving the products correctly ,use the parent category to retrieve the subcategory and within the loop retrieve the products .

Comment: which part of template code you want me to paste ?

Comment: where you are retrieving the products ?

Comment: i think this is it -

Comment: Are you using `parent` as argument when you are retrieving categories ?